# Does the Queen James Bible twist the original language the Scriptures were written in?

Tags: kjv

The QJV, a pro - homosexuality translation based off of the KJV, published in 2012 by an anonymous group of editors, removes all "homophobic" references, claiming that the first homophobic reference was in 1946 - furthermore, claiming that "most scholars" agree with them. What does the original language say? Do they have any footing at all?

For example:

Genesis 19:5 (KJV)

> And they called unto Lot, and said unto him, ‘Where are the men which came in to thee this night? Bring them out unto us, that we may know them’.

Leviticus 18:22 (KJV)

> Thou shalt not lie with mankind, as with womankind: it is abomination.

Leviticus 20:13 (KJV)

> If a man also lie with mankind, as he lieth with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination; they shall surely be put to death; their blood shall be upon them.

Romans 1:26–27 (KJV)

> For this cause God gave them up unto vile affections: for even their women did change the natural use into that which is against nature: And likewise also the men, leaving the natural use of the woman, burned in their lust one toward another; men with men working that which is unseemly, and receiving in themselves that recompense of their error which was meet.

Info: [What is the Queen James Bible?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Queen-James-Bible.html)

Comment: It seems they wish to correct the wording of prophets and apostles and the words of Jesus of Nazareth himself. The written word is what it is. One either  accepts what is written - or one rejects it all, by being a critic of it and therefore imposing oneself above it.

Comment: A link would be helpful to substantiate the detail above. And a quotation from the pages might be a useful example to demonstrate what alterations are being suggested.

Comment: I've been unable to find an online version on the QJV, and I've only had access to it once. However, I do have a link to an article about it.

Comment: @NigelJ, I don't know about the QJV specifically, but Wikipedia seems to substantiate the claim (see my Answer)... in a sense at least.

Comment: You will need to nominate some specific texts to examine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> the first homophobic reference was in 1946

This may be *partially* true, or perhaps, true in the sense of a technicality. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity_and_homosexuality), "the first instance of the English word 'homosexuals' used in a biblical translation was in [...] 1946". However, with respect to what Scripture *teaches*, this is about as relevant as saying that Scripture didn't condemn "gay people" prior to some date. But it should hardly be surprising that English translations circa 1800 don't condemn being happy! I imagine it's true that "most scholars" agree that the word "homosexual" and/or related words were not used prior to this.

If we want to know Scripture says about same-sex copulation, however, we need to look at *meanings* and not specific words used.

> What does the original language say?

In Genesis 19, the cities of Sodom and Gomorrah are destroyed for their great sin. One of these is illustrated in verse 5: "They called to Lot, 'Where are the men who came to you tonight? Bring them out to us, that we may [have sexual intercourse with] them.'" Lot's response is to declare this desire "wicked", and instead he tries to satisfy them by offering his virgin daughters, to "do to them as you please". Now, we ought rightly to be somewhat horrified by this, but let us not lose sight of the implication: what the Sodomites wanted to do was *worse* in Lot's eyes. Jude (1:7) also affirms that their wickedness was sexual and deviant in nature: "Sodom and Gomorrah [...] indulged in sexual immorality and pursued unnatural desire".

Leviticus 18:22 is more explicit: "you shall not lie with a male as with a woman; it is an abomination." This is reiterated in 20:13 which prescribes the death penalty for such acts. In the New Testament, speaking against the unrighteous, Paul (Romans 1:26-27) tells us that "God gave them up to dishonorable passions [...] their women exchanged natural relations for those that are contrary to nature; and the men likewise gave up natural relations with women and were consumed with passion for one another, men committing shameless acts with men and receiving in themselves the due penalty for their error." While other passages may use specific terms whose meaning is less clear, there is very little wiggle room in these passages to see what is being condemned as other than same-sex sexual relations. Even the great bastion of liberalism Wikipedia [agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity_and_homosexuality) that Christianity throughout history has generally condemned homosexual behavior.

From the very beginning, much Sin has had the same basis: "did God *really* say...?". It shouldn't surprise us that wicked, sinful humans try to twist God's word into saying what they want it to say. At least in this case, however, God's word is pretty clear: "from the beginning of creation, God made them male and female" (Mark 10:6, Genesis 1:27). It has always been God's design that one man and one woman should come together and "become one flesh" (Genesis 2:24); not a man with a man, or a woman with a woman.

To be sure, we can quibble over what is meant by "homophobic". Christianity has *always* taught that we are to follow in the example of Christ, who loved sinners. If we should turn people away because their hearts are inclined to sin, we would do well to start with ourselves, for we are all sinful. At the same time, "woe to those who call evil good" (Isaiah 5:20).

---

You may also find [this article](https://www.christianbwagner.com/post/arsenokoitai-and-homosexuality) helpful. It doesn't discuss the QJV specifically, but does discuss claims similar to those mentioned in the Question. Additionally, many scripture citations were provided by [this article](https://www.gotquestions.org/homosexuality-Bible.html) which also discusses homosexuality and Scripture. Finally, [the article cited in the Question](https://www.gotquestions.org/Queen-James-Bible.html) *does* discuss the QJV specifically along with the verses altered (many of which I quoted!). However, the alterations are nearly all suspect; some, quite obviously so, especially when compared to the original Hebrew and Greek texts.

---

Scripture quotations are taken from [ESV](https://www.esv.org/) (via [Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/)), but are consistent with other modern, mainstream translations, and the following key passages were also checked against https://biblehub.com/interlinear. So far as I can tell without a degree in biblical languages, there are no translation shenanigans here. For reference, here are the key passages in the original KJV:

> Where are the men which came in to thee this night? Bring them out unto us, that we may know them. (Genesis 19:5)

"Know" is thoroughly known to be a Hebrew euphemism for sexual intercourse, and, as noted, Jude 1:7 affirms the meaning here specifically by use of the Greek word "ἐκπορνεύσασαι" (note the root "πορνεία"/"porneia").

> Thou shalt not lie with mankind, as with womankind: it is abomination. (Leviticus 18:22)
>
> If a man also lie with mankind, as he lieth with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination: they shall surely be put to death.  (Leviticus 20:13)

The use of "mankind" here to mean "a[nother] male" is anachronistic, yet the intent is clear via the contrast with "womankind". It's also clear from this same contrasting (as well as surrounding context) that "lie with" is talking about intercourse and not simply sharing a sleeping place. Finally, it is clear that 18:22 is speaking to men; the repetition in 20:13 is explicit, and moreover, were it otherwise, one would have to argue that *heterosexual* intercourse is an abomination!

> And likewise also the men, leaving the natural use of the woman, burned in their lust one toward another; men with men working that which is unseemly. (Romans 1:27)

...and I have nothing to add. If the preceding verses gave insufficient wiggle room, this one gives none at all. At any rate, the only significant disparity between KJV and modern translations is the noted use of "mankind" / "womankind" rather than "a male" / "a woman".

Comment: It seems you're quoting from a translation/version other than the KJV. Could you perhaps provide your reason(s) for using that one instead of the KJV, as well as the reason(s) you believe that version is a better choice than the KJV or the QJV?

Comment: To be clear, I fully agree with you, but I think it would make this answer better to address these. Examples could be that the version quoted is also a well-attested scholarly modern translation, faithfully converting the meanings from the original languages to modern English instead of archaic English.

Comment: @JedSchaaf, quotations are from ESV, a modern, respected, and literal-leaning (as opposed to paraphrase-leaning) translation, and I also cross-checked the main verses against https://biblehub.com/interlinear/. No particular reason other than that happens to be what I use. KJV's language, as I'm sure you know, can be anachronistic. Mainstream, modern translations agree on the gist of the verses cited, and some even use more explicit language (e.g. NIV replaces the euphemism "know" with "have sex with").

Comment: @JedSchaaf, FYI, you can also see my thoughts on translation choice [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/97079/53502).

Comment: Note: I don't say that KJV is a "bad" translation, but one must be careful relying on it because 400 years is a long time in terms of language evolution, and (to a lesser extent) scholarship and availability of source manuscripts has improved since that time. For that reason, I consider modern, mainstream translations at least as authoritative, especially when one compares several translations and checks against the original text(s), as I've done here.

Comment: Indeed, some of the archaic English of the KJV may be difficult for many modern readers to understand, and a few terms are actually detrimental for accurate knowledge to the uninformed. (See Mark Ward's YouTube series on "False Friends in the KJV" for a number of such examples.) I personally prefer it, though, for its style and (for me) ease of memorization. The NASB, ESV, and CSB are my other preferences for study, if I'm not checking an interlinear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152337/discussion-between-matthew-and-jed-schaaf).

Answer (score 5):

The anonymous authors of the Queen James Bible claim that there was no reference to homosexuality in any Bible translation prior to the Revised Standard Version of 1946. Then, they assert, “anti-LGBT Bible interpretations” arose, based on a faulty translation in the RSV of eight verses. Further, they seem to have the idea that all Bible translations of these eight verses are wrong and that they are the only ones who have got it right.

Those eight verses are detailed in the *Got Questions* site with its link below, so anyone wanting to examine the matter of differing versions could go there. The conclusion of that site is:

> “What are their scholastic credentials? Where can seekers of truth go
> to verify their claims? Are we to believe that all other Bible
> translators succumbed to “interpretive ambiguity,” while only the
> editors of the QJV have seen the truth of the text?
>
> There is no textual support for the changes they have made to these
> eight passages pf Scripture. The only reason for making such changes
> is to accomplish their stated goal of making “homophobic
> interpretations impossible.” In other words, they are twisting the
> Word of God to suit their agenda.”
> [Does the Queen James Bible twist the original language the Scriptures were written in?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/93422/does-the-queen-james-bible-twist-the-original-language-the-scriptures-were-writt)

There is no need to go into detailed examination of all eight passages because they have not been translated. Some existing English words have had different English words used in their stead, that's all. Anybody can do that. Were the original language words in those eight passages even consulted? Until scholarly evidence is offered to justify that change in wording, it seems obvious that they were not. It also seems obvious that replacing former words with modern-day preferences of those with a vested interest in promoting homosexual matters, shows clear bias. Let the writers name themselves, state their credentials, and offer scholastic support for what they have done, then we can take them (and their version, for it is not a translation) seriously.

Comment: I would say that the editors of the QJV could even simply provide the reasoning and support for their alterations and still remain anonymous, if they so chose. The simple fact is, though, that their changes go against the original meanings and usages of the original Greek and Hebrew (and other) languages, even in non-biblical contexts contemporary to the original writers.